# how to dump part of fields of a special table under postgresql 8.1

Tags: database, postgresql, backup

how to dump part of fields of a special table under postgresql 8.1.
command 'pg_dump' ? or some commands else? 
could you please help with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: +1 for mentioning your version, thankyou. Too many people run terribly ancient versions and don't say so.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html).

With [your ancient Postgres 8.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/sql-copy.html) you can't use a `VIEW` or a `SELECT`. But you can specify columns to export.

`COPY` in modern Postgres can do a lot more.

You really should be upgrading to a current version. [Postgres 8.1 has been unsupported since 2010.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Comment: Great, that's really useful, thanks! Ya, I am new to postgresql, what's worse, our company use version 8.1 as product database.

Comment: @Zuckonit Then your company needs to update... about three years ago. Seriously. Almost every "how do I" question will get "In PostgreSQL 8.4 or newer..." type answers for you, and newer versions will "just work" with things like autovacuum where you're probably struggling. Not to mention likely performance issues.